# ¿Cómo hago para que el programa me reconozca 32 ejemplo como fila 3 columna 2 sin tener que solicitar ambos datos por separado?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una matriz pero en mi proyecto me piden que no solicite columna y fila por separado, como siempre se a hecho, sino que el usuario ponga 21 por ejemplo y el programa reconozca como fila 2 columna 1. No sé como hacerlo ¿me dan una ayuda?

```
    #include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main(void)
{
     int f,c,aux=0;
     int matriz[100][100];
     
     //lleno la matriz
     cout<<"\introducir Tamaño De La Fila:    ";
     cin>>f;
     cout<<"\introducir Tamaño De La Columna: ";
     cin>>c;
     cout<<endl;
```

Por poner un ejemplo vean este código: se pide la fila y columna por separado pero yo necesito que al poner 35 el programa valide de una vez que sería fila 3 columna 5.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! lo tomas como string, partis el string en 2, convertis esas dos partes en enteros... y listo....

Comment: ¿El número  siempre es de dos cifras?

Comment: Si vos reescribis la pregunta, entonces las respuestas dejan de tener sentido, y entonces los que se tomaron la molestia en contestarte perdieron su tiempo porque  ademas de no aceptar ninguna respuesta, no votaste ninguna si servia. Tu pregunta fue clara, y las respuestas que te dieron respondieron tu problema. Ahora, si tenes otro problema, hace otra pregunta....

Answer (score 1):

Si la cifra solamente es de dos cifras lo que tienes que dividir:

```
     cout<<"\introducir Tamaño De La Fila:    ";
     cin>>f;

     int columna = f%10;  // Resto de la división
     int fila = f/10;     //  Divides
```

Comment: ok muchas gracias, si es de 2 cifras solo, gracias lo pondre en practica

Comment: hola @Juan Carlos Guibovich e intentando poner en practica lo que me avias dicho pero aun no e podido basicamente porque mi programa debe de eliminar el valor de la fila y posicion que digite pero nose en si como deberia hacerlo, edite la publicacion para que veas mas omenos como queria hacerlo

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer. Veo que tiene una matriz  bidimensional de 100x100.  Pero si la fila y columna solo toman un dígito entero, solo puedes tener una matriz de 10x10 (del 0 al 9). Ahora si por error has puesto la matriz[100][100] en lugar de matriz[10][10] entendería  que quieres poner poner en esa matriz  alguna marca en base de lo ingresado por  el usuario. Por ejemplo, si ponen 32, entonces, el valor de la fila 3 column 2 se borra el  de la matriz. ¿Algo de eso? Pero esa matriz no tiene nada---¿?

Comment: encerio no sabia perdon are otra pregunta entonces, es que soy nuevo aqui, pero si es una matriz[10][10] entonces cuando yo meto 32 se debe eliminar el elemento de la posicion fila 3 columna 2 entonces si es como tu lo dices, ese elemento debe de borrarse, si que raro ya me di cuenta que no pude codificarlo, creo que mejor are otra pregunta pero si, ee yo avia modificado la pregunta y avia echo un programa mas acoplado a mi pregunta entonces gracias, creo que are otra pregunta mejor, perdon si ocasione inconvenientes

Comment: y como podria votar las respuestas? porque si me resultaron utilices

Comment: Vota por la que te resultó más útil

Comment: y ya hice otra pregunta talves te puedas tomar el tiempo de leerla si no tienes nada que hacer

Comment: nose como votar una pregunta

Answer (score 1):

La solución es posible siempre y cuando la cantidad de dígitos a ingresar sean pares, porque si es un número impar ejemplo: 356 va existir 2 casos:

1. fila=3; columna=56
2. fila=35; columna=6
   En caso tenga 2 o 4 dígitos, una de las soluciones sería:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <string>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main(void)
{
     int numero;
     int fila;
     int columna;
     string fc;     
   
     cout<<"\introducir numero de fila-columna:  ";
     cin>>fc;     
     numero=std::string(fc).size();
     switch(numero){
        case 2: fila=atoi(fc.c_str())/10;
                columna=atoi(fc.c_str())%10;
                cout<<"Fila: "<<fila<<endl;
                cout<<"Columna: "<<columna<<endl;
                break;
        case 4: fila=atoi(fc.c_str())/100;
                columna=atoi(fc.c_str())%100;
                cout<<"Fila: "<<fila<<endl;
                cout<<"Columna: "<<columna<<endl; 
                break; 
        default:cout<<"Se necesitan mas detalle"<<endl;     
     } 
 }
```

Comment: ok gracias, si en mi proyecto solo es una de 2 digitos entonces con 2 digitos ya es suficiente muchas gracias por la respuesta las pondre en practica gracias

Comment: hola @joshin e intentado poner en practica lo que me enceño pero aun no e podido porque mi programa consiste en eliminar elementos de una matriz y cuando creo el if con el fc me dice que no es permitido y nose de que otra forma hacerlo

Comment: edite la publicacion porque no pude comentar aqui el codigo

Comment: mi programa consiste en eliminar posiciones de una matriz a partir de insertar fila y columna debo convertirlas a 0